# invertibility of $f^{-1}$

Tags: functions

In my introductory maths book there is a statement (it follows a theorem) that says:"Note that if f is one-to-one, then $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f$, and so $f^{-1}$ is invertible and also one-to-one because of the previous theorem" [The theorem says that a function is invertible if and only if it is one-to-one, it makes perfect sense to me]

Why can we conclude that $f^{-1}$ is invertible and that its inverse equals $f$ only with the previous information? Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(f^{-1} o f)(x)=x$ and $(fof^{-1})(x)=x$, so by definition of inverse of a function, $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$.

An invertible function has to be 1-1, and so, $f^{-1}$ is 1-1.

Comment: You can use \circ for function composition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's way to think about it: we say that $f$ is invertible if there is a map (that is, a function) $f^{-1}$ for which $(f \circ f^{-1})(x) = (f^{-1}\circ f)(x) = x$.

Now, for $f^{-1}$ to be invertible, we'd need to find a map $(f^{-1})^{-1}$ for which $( f^{-1}\circ (f^{-1})^{-1})(x) = (f^{-1})^{-1}\circ f^{-1})(x) = x$.  Do we have such a map?  Sure!  If we put $f$ in for $(f^{-1})^{-1}$, we just get the same equations as before.

Answer (score 0):

A function is invertible if and only if it is a bijection (one-to-one and *onto*).

Why?

If $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is only one-to-one and we want to define $f^{-1} : Y \rightarrow X$ (such that $f \circ f^{-1} = i_Y$ and $f^{-1} \circ f = i_X$), what do we do about the elements in $Y$ which do not get mapped to by $f$? The inverse acting on these are meaningless because the is nothing in $X$ that gets mapped to them. So the compositions fail for some elements because their preimage is simply non-existent.

Now, if given a invertible function then it follows immediately that $f^{-1}$ is also invertible by simply working backwards from the definition of a bijection.

The above seems rather pedantic but this is the way things are defined. If we take $Y$ from the above discussion to be $f(X) = \{ f(x) : x \in X \}$, then we can drop then assumption of onto because all elements are being accounted for.